# Receiving data over STM32F407 or STM32L476's USB OTG using DMA?

Tags: dma, stm32f4discovery, usb-otg

I am working on a project and I need to receive data over USB OTG using DMA, but I could not find any channel link to it. I have configured DMA but I don't know which channel to link with it ( __HAL_LINKDMA(**HANDLE**, **PPP_DMA_FIELD**, **DMA_HANDLE**), somebody help me please....

Regards,

Waqas A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB HS peripheral is already a bus master.  Effectively it has the DMA built in so it doesn't need to use the general purpose DMA.

There are examples in the respective Cube package.  Eg: for STM32F4xx, see [STM32CubeF4](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef4.html).

Comment: Can you provide me with an example, so I can use it? Nothing is helping me. There is no such content available which can help me.

Comment: There are examples in the STM32Cube package, have you tried them?

Comment: No I haven't, can you provide a link or something?

Comment: Hello! Well I downloaded those packages but couldn't find any examples for USB. It has a lot of examples for GPIO, UART. Can you be more specific? I need it urgently

Comment: Did you try extracting the zip file and searching for files with 'USB' in the name?  Eg: here is one that emulates a USB mouse: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/tree/master/Projects/STM32F429ZI-Nucleo/Applications/USB_Device/HID_Standalone